# Minecraft skin missing texure

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: My hair used to look like this]

[image: Now it looks like this]

[Here is a link to the skin itself](https://minecraft.novaskin.me/skin/6144139851202560/Ichigo-Final-Getsuga-Tenshou)

The first picture shows how my hair used to look on the character, the second screenshot shows how it looks now... current version I am playing is 1.13

If anyone know how to fix the problem at all it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the link provided, it seems like the hair is part of the second layer of the skin, and the option that controls the visibility of this layer has been toggled off. To show the second layer of the head, navigate to Options >  Skin Customization > Hat: On.

For reference, you can learn more about skins by going to the Skin page in the official Minecraft Wiki [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Skin), as well as the Skin Customization menu [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options#Skin_customization).

Comment: ^^ Please consider marking this answer as accepted by clicking on the tick button underneath downvote.